# AWS JS SDK S3 HeadObject command throws error "check whether you have installed the "@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt" package explicitly"

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs, sigv4

I am deploying a lambda function through CDK. The function uses the aws-sdk for nodejs to send a HeadObject request to a multi region access point (MRAP).
When i send this HeadObject request, the sdk throws an error with this message:

```
Please check whether you have installed the "@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt" package explicitly. 
You must also register the package by calling [require("@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt");] or an ESM equivalent such as [import "@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt";]. 
For more information please go to https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3#functionality-requiring-aws-common-runtime-crt
```

I tried following the steps mentioned in the [github link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3#functionality-requiring-aws-common-runtime-crt), but the error persists. Strangely, when i download the lambda source code, I can clearly see the package inside node_modules
[image: extracted lambda function code]

My code roughly looks like:

```
import '@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt'

import { HeadObjectCommand, S3Client, NotFound } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'

export const s3ObjectExists = async (): Promise<boolean> => {
  const s3 = new S3Client()
  const bucket = '{MRAP ARN}'
  const key = 'key for s3 item'

  try {
    // throws
    await client.send(
      new HeadObjectCommand({
        Key: key,
        Bucket: bucket,
      })
    )
    return true
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof NotFound) {
      return false
    }

    // This statement is logging, so it's -not- a NotFound error
    log.error('Failed to check if object exists', { error: e })
    throw e
  }
}
```

In case anyone asks, the s3 api supports the bucket being the ARN of an MRAP. I'm able to run the AWS CLI equivalent of this code just fine. (`aws s3api head-object --key {key} --bucket {MRAP arn}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of my problem - It was actually two issues.
First, I needed to include `aws-crt` in the `bundlingOptions.nodeModules` prop in the NodeJsFunction CDK construct. This tells CDK to install the package, in the lambda, rather than building it into the CDK bundle. Interestingly, I did not need to include `aws-crt` in my `package.json` at all.

This resulted in `UnknownError` being thrown when calling the HeadObject command. This was due to the lambda missing the policy that grants `S3:GetObject`.

Once i had both of these fixes in place, the issue went away.